# Singularity of $V(Y^2-X^3-X)\to\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

In "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, in example I.3.7, Silverman define $\Phi:V(Y^2Z-X^3-X^2Z)\to\mathbb{P}^1$ with $\Phi(X,Y,Z)=[Y,X]$. He says that $\Phi$ is not regular at $[0,0,1]$. How to prove it?

Comment: Compute the partial derivatives at the designated point. I think it works out to be 0.

Comment: Yes, the partial derivatives are $-3X^2-2XZ,2YZ,Y^2-X^2$, which all vanish at $[0,0,1]$.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm talking about the mapping $\Phi$ and not the curve $V(Y^2Z-X^3-X^2Z)$. But maybe is there a link between singularity of the curve and (non)regularity of the map? Maybe if $V\simeq\mathbb{P}^1$ then $V$ must be regular at all point?